# How to get Popup Login form in HtmlUnit

Tags: html, selenium, authentication, popup, htmlunit

Hi i am developing a software in that i need to login a popup ,but i cant get form and input(email)and password but i tried with java selenium in that i logged in successfuly but i cant in htmlunit(the website is https://www.aaafx.com/BinaryOptions.aspx) in that Demo account Login,

Code is:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);

    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(180000);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);



   HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

    page.getHtmlElementById("sopDemoLogin").click();
    System.out.println("Login clicked     :"+page.getHtmlElementById("sopDemoLogin").getId());


    HtmlTextInput email = page.getElementByName("email");
    HtmlPasswordInput password = page.getElementByName("password");
    email.click();
    email.setValueAttribute("email");
    password.click();
    password.setValueAttribute("password");
    System.out.println("Email : "+email.getValueAttribute());
    System.out.println("password : "+password.getValueAttribute());
```

but it is showing another form text input and password intput
not in demo account login form
Thanks in advance